# (DX12 Shadow Mapping) Depth buffer is always filled with 1

Tags: directx, shadow, depth-buffer, directx-12

I'm really new to graphics programming in general, so please bear with me. I am trying to add shadow mapping from a distant light (orthogonal projection) into my scene, but when I follow the (very incomplete) steps from Frank Luna's DX12 book I find that my SRV for the shadow map is just filled with depths of 1.

If it helps, here is my SRV definition:

```
D3D12_TEX2D_SRV texDesc = {
        0,
        -1,
        0,
        0.0f
    };
    D3D12_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC srvDesc = {
        DXGI_FORMAT_R32_TYPELESS,
        D3D12_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D,
        D3D12_DEFAULT_SHADER_4_COMPONENT_MAPPING,
    };
    srvDesc.Texture2D = texDesc;

    m_device->CreateShaderResourceView(m_lightDepthTexture.Get(),&srvDesc, m_cbvHeap->GetCPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart());
```

and here are my DSV heap and descriptor definitions:

```
D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_DESC dsvHeapDesc = {};
    dsvHeapDesc.NumDescriptors = 2;
    dsvHeapDesc.Type = D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_TYPE_DSV;
    dsvHeapDesc.Flags = D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_FLAG_NONE;
    ThrowIfFailed(m_device->CreateDescriptorHeap(&dsvHeapDesc, IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_dsvHeap)));

    D3D12_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC depthStencilDesc = {};
    depthStencilDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D32_FLOAT;
    depthStencilDesc.ViewDimension = D3D12_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
    depthStencilDesc.Flags = D3D12_DSV_FLAG_NONE;

    CD3DX12_HEAP_PROPERTIES heapProps = CD3DX12_HEAP_PROPERTIES(D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_DEFAULT);
    CD3DX12_RESOURCE_DESC resourceDesc = CD3DX12_RESOURCE_DESC::Tex2D(DXGI_FORMAT_R32_TYPELESS, m_width, m_height, 1, 0, 1, 0, D3D12_RESOURCE_FLAG_ALLOW_DEPTH_STENCIL);

    D3D12_CLEAR_VALUE depthOptimizedClearValue = {};
    depthOptimizedClearValue.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D32_FLOAT;
    depthOptimizedClearValue.DepthStencil.Depth = 1.0f;
    depthOptimizedClearValue.DepthStencil.Stencil = 0;

    ThrowIfFailed(m_device->CreateCommittedResource(
        &heapProps,
        D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_NONE,
        &resourceDesc,
        D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_DEPTH_WRITE,
        &depthOptimizedClearValue,
        IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_dsvBuffer)
    ));

    D3D12_RESOURCE_DESC texDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&texDesc, sizeof(D3D12_RESOURCE_DESC));
    texDesc.Dimension = D3D12_RESOURCE_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
    texDesc.Alignment = 0;
    texDesc.Width = m_width;
    texDesc.Height = m_height;
    texDesc.DepthOrArraySize = 1;
    texDesc.MipLevels = 1;
    texDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32_TYPELESS;
    texDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    texDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    texDesc.Layout = D3D12_TEXTURE_LAYOUT_UNKNOWN;
    texDesc.Flags = D3D12_RESOURCE_FLAG_ALLOW_DEPTH_STENCIL;

    ThrowIfFailed(m_device->CreateCommittedResource(
        &heapProps,
        D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_NONE,
        &texDesc,
        D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_GENERIC_READ,
        &depthOptimizedClearValue,
        IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_lightDepthTexture)
    ));


    CD3DX12_CPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE dsv(m_dsvHeap->GetCPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart());
    m_device->CreateDepthStencilView(m_dsvBuffer.Get(), &depthStencilDesc, dsv);
    dsv.Offset(1, m_device->GetDescriptorHandleIncrementSize(D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_TYPE_DSV));

    m_device->CreateDepthStencilView(m_lightDepthTexture.Get(), &depthStencilDesc, dsv);
```

I then created a basic vertex shader that just transforms the vertices with my map (from Frank Luna's book, page 648,650). Since I bound the m_lightDepthTexture to D3D12GraphicsCommandList::OMSetRenderTargets, I assumed that the depth values would be written onto m_lightDepthTexture. But simply sampling this texture in my main pass proves that the values are actually 1.0f. So nothing actually happened on my shadow pass!

I really have no idea what to ask, but if anyone has a sample DX12 shadow map I could see (Google comes up with DX11 or less, or much too complicated samples), or if there's a good source to learn about this, please let me know!

EDIT: I should say that I changed the format from DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT, as I think the extra 8 bits for stencil is irrelevant to my case. I changed back to the book format and nothing changed, so I think this format should be fine.

Comment: Can you try putting your format for SRV to DXGI_FORMAT_R32_FLOAT and not DXGI_FORMAT_R32_TYPELESS? Have you enabled debug layer? (If you don't know you can find it easily)

Comment: I tried this earlier, but I get an error that the format must match that of the clear value. I have also enabled the debug layer.

Comment: I also adopted Luna's shadow map class in my game without issue. Agree with @mateeeeeee that srvDesc.Format cannot be _R32_TYPELESS. If _R32_FLOAT didn't work, try `DXGI_FORMAT_R24_UNORM_X8_TYPELESS`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately this change doesn't change my output at all. I found that it is possible to alter the texture, which I found by setting the return position of my shadow VS to 0.0f. This caused half of my texture to be 0 and the other half to be 1. For some reason this is the only change I could make that affected my resource.

Comment: You are doing something fundamentally different to Luna's example in the book, which renders correctly. I suggest a line by line comparison of the code to identify where you have deviated.. it's usually the best way to debug what's going wrong.

Comment: You have the code repository somewhere public?

Comment: @mateeeeeee I just created one: https://github.com/hlembeck/DX12-Test-Bench. I messed with some sampler settings here, and I also messed with the transforms to try and alter the result. Now I find that the comparison function doesn't work (compare always gives one extreme, compare never gives other extreme, and compare less_equal goes to one of those extremes... despite having the comparison value strictly between 0 and 1). I'll look at that more later.

Comment: @MaicoDeBlasio I'm not entirely sure where to find Luna's actual code, as he only provides snippets (in the version I have). I've been jumping around that book, so my code is unlikely to have the same structure as his. That said, I reformatted my shadow map code to something similar to his, and this is in my github repository (linked above).

Comment: The source for Luna's DX12 book is [here](https://github.com/d3dcoder/d3d12book)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the unecessary `return ret;` from your shadow vertex shader, the problem then seems to be in winding order of vertices of your sphere. You can easily verify this by setting cull mode to `D3D12_CULL_MODE_NONE` for your shadow PSO.

You can easily correct your sphere winding order by switching order of any two vertices of every triangle, so wherever you have `p1,p2,p3` you just write it for example as `p1,p3,p2`.

You will also need to check your matrix multiplication order in your vertex shaders, I didn't checked it in detail but it's inconsistent and I believe the cause why the sphere will appear black when you fix the above issue. You also seem to be missing division by `w` for your light coords in lighting vertex shader.

Comment: Ah, that ret definitely was an issue, oops! Thank you! I was messing with this thing so much that I changed pretty much all the relevant code in the shaders to alter stuff. I think the winding order is correct, but the order of multiplication could have prevented the correct computation.